# Django - Enlaces a editar fila añadiendo en la url la ID

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Al hacer en el template el enlace, me devuelve error:
(En este caso es a la página update con el id o pk para su edición).

Escribiendo diréctamente en el navegador con cualquier pk funciona bien:

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/estacion/update_station/1/**

(pero con el código url en el template me devuelve error)

Código:

```
{% for station in stations %}

    href="{% 'stations:modificar_estacion' station.id %}

{% endfor %}
```

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `{% station.id %}` no es una etiqueta, por eso el error, por otra parte la etiqueta `{% url ... %}`, **genera una URL**, que recibe como primer argumento un nombre de patrón de URL, dudo que `'estacion/update_station'` sea un nombre de patrón de URL, supongo que no sabes aun como funciona la etiqueta `url`, investiga como funciona, pues por lo que veo no tienes ni la menor idea de lo que es la etiqueta `url` o como funciona, [visita la documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: Supongo que te refieres que a la url le llamamos mediante el name que le asignamos, y no utilizando una url tal cual... (No se si lo dices por eso) Pero como bien dices, mucha idea no tengo, estoy aprendiendo poco a poco. Url con parámetros para el CRUD es lo que estoy investigando. Gracias por el enlace Julio Cesar.

Comment: Así es, suerte! :)

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada `{% station.id %}` no es una etiqueta, por eso el error.

Por otra parte la etiqueta o *template tag* [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url), **genera una URL** y recibe como primer argumento un [**nombre de patrón de URL**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns), dudo que `'estacion/update_station'` sea un nombre de patrón de URL entonces supongo que no sabes aun como funciona la etiqueta [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

La etiqueta `url`, como dije anteriormente recibe como primer argumento el nombre del patrón de URL y los argumentos adicionales deben ser valores separados por espacios que se utilizarán como argumentos en la URL, es decir la etiqueta `url` debería quedar así:

```
{% url 'stations:modificar_estacion' station.id %}
```

También podrías utilizar *sintaxis de palabras clave* (no se como se llama el parámetro de la URL, pero supongo que sera `pk`):

```
{% url 'stations:modificar_estacion' pk=station.id %}
```

De esta manera la etiqueta `url` generaría la URL que quieres correctamente. Espero haberte ayudado.